# How can I connect visual studio 2012 with sql server 2012 database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am building a website by using mvc4 code first approach. I have a problem when I tried to connect with sql server 2012. it does not connect with remote sql server database. it gives me an error " the webproject rewrite requires sql server express which installed on this computer. 
my connection string in webconfig as follow:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="StoreDataContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=server=.;
         Initial Catalog=aspnet-Demo-20150421090714;
         Integrated Security=SSPI;
         AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\books.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My sql server name is: WINDOWS8_1-PC
Authentication: Window authentication

can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Your connection string seems to be wrong. "Data Source=server=.;" ?

Comment: I found a tutorial on connection string that put "Data Source=server=.;" reason he gave was " windows authentication"

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try this:

> `<connectionStrings>
>        <add name="StoreDataContext" 
>            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
>            Initial Catalog=aspnet-Demo-20150421090714;
>            Integrated Security=SSPI;
>            AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\books.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

**.\SQLEXPRESS** is equals to **ServerName\SQLInstanceName**

---

2. Copy the **books.mdf** file to the server disk.

   2.1 Attach the database through the SQL Management Studio.

   2.2 Configure your Connection String like this:

> `<connectionStrings>
>        <add name="StoreDataContext" 
>            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
>            Initial Catalog=books;
>            Integrated Security=SSPI; 
>            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Sorry!!! in the Data Source of the connection string must be like this:Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS. Also the Server appears not attaching the database. the |DataDirectory| yo must change for the full path of the .mdf file, if the mdf file is not on the server disk, attach to the database fails.

Comment: I changed the way u said and did not give me any error used to give but books.mdf file does not exist in appdata folder of visual studio as well there is no database created in the name of books in sql server.

Comment: am getting this error"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" and tried by changin port in to 1433 but giving me the same error